# How to handle different important variables, including overlapping information, in regression?

Tags: regression, causality, dag

I am interested in **smoking_ads** effect on **smoking_rate**. I also have two categorical confounders in the data: **town** and **year**.

**Possible DAG shows two backdoors that need to be closed in conditioning.** Each town may have different characteristics that possibly have an effect on ads (laws) or smoking rate (habitational factors).

[image]

**However, my data is a bit tricky as its detailedness is limited.** Smoking_ads is calculated for each town by study year: the values of "smoking_ads" are very similar for each town. For example, town "C" values range between 22-24 and town D between 233-257.

[image]

To illustrate, a stupid analogy of this is would be the following model:

```
weight ~ sex + breast_size
```

**1) Should I adjust for town or not?** It seems, et adding town kills the effect. How you handle such situations?

**2) How does it differ if "town" is added as a another level into model + (1 |town)?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> 1. Should I adjust for town or not? It seems, et adding town kills the effect. How you handle such situations?

Yes, you will want to include `town` in your model because it is a confounder according to the DAG.

> 2. How does it differ if "town" is added as a another level into model + (1 |town)?

Not only is it a confounder according to your DAG but you also have repeated measures. Provided you have sufficient of them, random intercepts are a good way to do this. Fitting fixed effects will also achieve the same thing. You might want to check the answer here, to a related question:
[How do random effects adjust for confounding in a model?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/473832/how-do-random-effects-adjust-for-confounding-in-a-model/474027#474027)

Comment: Thank you so much Robert! The link you provided was very enlightening!